# geom_bar two datasets together in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have two `dataframes` with `two` columns each, that I would like to plot `together` as a `barplot` using `ggplot` in `R` as shown below:

[image]

How can I do this using `dplyr` in R?

Sample Data:

```
DF1

Code Count_2020
A    1
B    2
C    3
D    4
E    5
F    6

DF2

Code Count_2021
A    4
B    8
C    6
D    8
E    10
F    12
```

So, I first thought of merging the two `dataframes` into one using `dplyr::inner_join`, and I got a new `dataframe` as shown below:

```
Code Count_2021 Count_2020
 A          4          1
 B          8          2
 C          6          3
 D          8          4
 E         10          5
 F         12          6
```

Next I thought of using `dplyr::gather` to plot the count data from both years together as `Type` and `Value`, but this messed up the gathered dataframe as the output changed to:

```
Type Value
Code A 
Code B
Code C
Code D
Code E
Code F
```

Code I tried

```
library(tidyverse)

# Merge DF1 and DF2 
DF = inner_join(DF1, DF2)

# Gather data for plotting
Gathered_DF= DF%>% dplyr::select(Code, Count_2020, Count_2021) %>% 
    gather(key = Type, value = Value) # Output not as expected, stuck!!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` after the join and then use `geom_col` in `ggplot2` with `position` specified as 'dodge' and `fill` as 'Year`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
inner_join(DF1, DF2) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -Code, names_to = 'Year', names_prefix = 'Count_') %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = Code, y = value, fill = Year)) + 
     geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
     theme_bw()
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
DF1 <- structure(list(Code = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 
 Count_2020 = 1:6), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

DF2 <- structure(list(Code = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), Count_2021 = c(4L, 
8L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pivot_longer` instead of `gather` as it is superseded in `tidyr 1.1.3`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(Code = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
                  Count_2020 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
df2 <- data.frame(Code = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
                  Count_2021 = c(4, 8, 6, 8, 10, 12))
df_joined <- df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by = "Code") %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = !Code, names_to = "Year", names_prefix = "Count_", values_to = "Count")
df_joined
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>    Code  Year  Count
#>    <fct> <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 A     2020      1
#>  2 A     2021      4
#>  3 B     2020      2
#>  4 B     2021      8
#>  5 C     2020      3
#>  6 C     2021      6
#>  7 D     2020      4
#>  8 D     2021      8
#>  9 E     2020      5
#> 10 E     2021     10
#> 11 F     2020      6
#> 12 F     2021     12

ggplot(df_joined, aes(x = Code, y = Count, fill = Year)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

In the code above, the argument inside `pivot_longer` are:

- `cols = !Code` it means the column to be pivoted that is all column except `Code`
- `names_to = "Year"` it means the name of column to be created for grouping
- `names_prefix = "Count_"` is used to remove the string `"Count_"` from the created column `"Year"`
- `values_to = "Count"` it means the name of column to created for stored value from each group.

You can learn more about this function by simply call `?pivot_longer`

Comment: Oh, I don't realize someone answered before me, I typed my answer too long. Should I just delete my answer? Since it's basically the same

Comment: This is a good answer. You should keep it

Answer (score 2):

Use `pivot_longer()` to reshape your data then plot using `ggplot`.
Bonus: to add text on the bars, use `geom_bar_text` from the `ggfittext` package

```r
library(tidyverse)

DF1 <- read.table(text = "Code Count_2020
A    1
B    2
C    3
D    4
E    5
F    6", header = TRUE)

DF2 <- read.table(text = "Code Count_2021
A    4
B    8
C    6
D    8
E    10
F    12", header = TRUE)

DF <- left_join(DF1, DF2, by = "Code")
DF_long <- DF %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Code,
               names_to = c("tmp", "Year"),
               names_sep = "\\_",
               values_to = "Count") %>% 
  select(-tmp)
DF_long
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>    Code  Year  Count
#>    <chr> <chr> <int>
#>  1 A     2020      1
#>  2 A     2021      4
#>  3 B     2020      2
#>  4 B     2021      8
#>  5 C     2020      3
#>  6 C     2021      6
#>  7 D     2020      4
#>  8 D     2021      8
#>  9 E     2020      5
#> 10 E     2021     10
#> 11 F     2020      6
#> 12 F     2021     12

plt <- ggplot(DF_long, aes(x = Code,
                           y = Count,
                           fill = Year)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  theme_minimal()
plt
```

[image]

```r
library(ggfittext)
plt +
  geom_bar_text(position = "dodge", reflow = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I also found another way of doing it:

```
library(tidyverse)
DF1 = data.frame(Code = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
                  Count_2020 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
DF2 = data.frame(Code = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
                  Count_2021 = c(4, 8, 6, 8, 10, 12))

DF_Merged = 
  inner_join(DF1, DF2)

DFF_Merged = DF_Merged %>% dplyr::select(Code, Count_2020, Count_2021) %>% 
  gather(key = Type, value = Value, -Code) %>% 
  mutate(Type = ifelse(Type == "Count_2020", "2020", "2021"))

DFF_Merged %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Code,Value), y = Value, fill = Type, 
             text = paste("Count:", Value,
                          "<br>", "Offense Code:", Code,
                          "<br>", "Year:", Type))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge", show.legend = FALSE) +
  xlab("Offense Code") +
  ylab("Count") +
  ggtitle("Arrest Counts for Group 1 in Year 2020 and  2021") +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=8))
```

Result

[image]