# geom_bar combine 2 dataset onto one graph

Tags: r, geom-bar

I have two dataframes with paired scores, each scoring patients on a 1-8 scoring system (Where 1= managing well and 8 = terminally ill).
One score is done by the patient and one by the clinician.

sample data

```
df <- data.frame(Patient = c(1,1,2,4,5,3,2,6,7,6,3,4,2,3,5,6,7,3,8,1), Clinican= c(1,2,2,5,4,5,4,4,4,2,3,5,4,6,5,4,3,7,7,1))
```

I'd like to create a bar chart similar to the one below using my dataset.
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.
I believe I need `dplyr` `pivot_longer` similar to this post:
[geom_bar two datasets together in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68674757/geom-bar-two-datasets-together-in-rpivot_longer)

Comment: What about the x axis information? Your data should have something with "very fit", "well"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `pivot_longer` and `geom_bar` as you asked.

### Libraries

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

### Solution

You can change `name` and `value` for whatever name you prefer.

Also, the x-axis is categorical, so we have to `mutate` it to `factor`.

You can then recode the factor `value` for the labels you need (e.g., 'well', 'very fit'...)

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(Patient:Clinican, names_to = "name", values_to = "value") %>% 
  mutate(value = factor(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: thank you that works perfectly. 

I just need to relabel 1 as "very fit" up to 8 as "terminally ill". is that by changing ```mutate(value = factor(value))``` in your workings.

Also is it possible to add confidence intervals/ error bars to the bar plots?

Comment: Yes, you are correct about how to recode. Here are some resources to add CI or SE: https://r-graph-gallery.com/4-barplot-with-error-bar.html